# Using unnest function in R language to split excel cells of a certain column based on regex, getting repetitive results

Tags: r, regex, excel, tidyr, unnest

I have a question, currently I am trying to split cells in an excel file, in a way that I can split each line if that line begins with a digit (and the plus for double digit numbers) and the number is followed by full stop ".", that is, defined by a regular expression that is defined in this function. However, when the actual splitting happens, the output is repetitive (looped) based on other columns.

Here you can find my [input data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p72GIdeWpNwE8dLV0zjV1Ad7saz8_DV1/view?usp=drivesdk), [current output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HuiqaHPetceEUXL0YNKOMDkrJK1e-cqp/view?usp=drivesdk) and this is the [desired output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11NxYrImaxqoB56IgpVR0_DYu2wI6Hydn/view?usp=drivesdk).

```
# Load libraries
library('tidyverse')
library('readxl')
library('openxlsx')

# Set functions
do_split = function(x, pattern = "\\d+\\.\\s{1}"){
if( is_tibble(x) ){ x = pull(x) }
num_bullets = x %>% str_extract_all("\\d+\\. ") %>% unlist
x %>% str_split(pattern) %>% unlist %>% .[.!=""] %>% str_c(num_bullets,.) %>% list %>% return
}
# Read data
df = read_excel(path = '~/Desktop/master.xlsx')


# Wrangle data
o = df %>%
mutate(Result = Result %>% do_split, Steps  = Steps %>% do_split) %>%
unnest(Result, Steps)
# Output file
write.xlsx(x = o, file = “out.xlsx”)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't provide links to files: they go stale (e.g., disabled/deleted), at which point this question goes unreproducible. Could you provide a sample of each? I don't think the use of `openxlsx` is relevant for your question, so it would be useful to provide the output something like `dput(head(df))`,  and the same for `current` and `expected` outputs. (You might need to change the number of lines to `head` if you need more for practical purposes, such as to properly show variety in the data.)

Comment: also please dont copy `rm(list=ls())` in your questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `rowwise()` so your mutate command is used on one row at a time...

```
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(Result, Steps), funs(do_split(.))) %>% 
  unnest()
```

if you don't need the delimiter (in your case the leading number, e.g. "1. "), `tidyr::separate_rows()` might be easier/cleaner...

```
df %>% 
  separate_rows(Result, Steps, sep = "\\d+\\. ") %>% 
  filter(Result != "")
```